# How do I render afresh in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="target"></div>
        <script src="//fb.me/react-0.12.1.js"></script>
        <script src="//fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/jsx">
            React.render(
              <h1>Hello, world! {new Date().toISOString()}</h1>,
              document.getElementById('target')
              );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is rendering a string like "Hello, world! 2014-12-16T18:45:22.022Z" in the browser, but it isn't updating unless I reload the page.

How do I get XYZ to load dynamically, in this case so that the date string will be kept up to date (no pun intended)?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered accepting one of the answers below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got back feedback:

My code was only rendering once because React.render() was called only once. The behavior I wanted could be obtained by putting the React.render() call inside an interval.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering should be pure (return same result if input is the same), so the react way is to do this instead:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.update, 16),
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },
    update: function() {
        this.setState({date: new Date()});
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {date: new Date()};
    },
    render: function() {
        // This is pure because it always render the same result if this.date doesn't change
        return <h1>Hello, world! {this.state.date.toISOString()}</h1>
    }
});

   React.render(
      <Hello />,
      document.getElementById('target')
      );
```